# Struct assignment and persistence in memory (C language)

Tags: c, arrays, struct

I apologize if this question is basic - I'm very new to C and still a little unsure on how arrays get handled, versus pointers (to arrays), in memory. (For example, as discussed [here](https://bytes.com/topic/c/answers/670947-struct-assignment).)

The following snippets are similar to the problem I encountered. Suppose I have structs List and Sublist, defined like so, inside an :

```
typedef struct {
char items[MAX_NUM_ITEMS][MAX_ITEM_LENGTH];
int num_items;
} Sublist;

typedef struct {
Sublist sublists[MAX_NUM_SUBLISTS];
int num_sublists;
} List;
```

and I have a function which takes a pointer to a List in hopes of modifying it. For example

```
void add_item_to_sublist(List *list, int sublist_number, const char *new_item) {...
```

with the goal to (if valid, which I'm kind of glossing over) append a new item to the specified sublist.

At one point I essentially did the following:

```
Sublist current = list->sublists[sublist_number];
```

and then performed the operation of appending new_item to current. Maybe it doesn't surprise you, but this failed. When trying to figure out what went wrong, it occurred to me that the problem might be related to the pass-by-value paradigm, so I tried

```
Sublist *current = &list->sublists[sublist_number];
```

instead - and this worked.

So here's my confusion. On the one hand, I get that there is a pass-by-value issue, so if current only lives in the frame of my function, then obviously it'll get wiped out, along with my modifications, after the function terminates. But on the other hand, I thought that assignment with structs was in memory, i.e. a "reference copy" situation - so I thought originally that any change to current (the first version) would automatically change sublists[sublist_number] as well.

Can someone help me understand my mistake?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is not related to pass-by-value which is something related to argument passing to functions (which may lead to similar problems) but the fact that you are assigning to a `Sublist` variable.

```
Sublist current;
```

It's a problem of semantics. `current` is an instance of `Sublist`, not an alias to something, not a pointer but a whole `Sublist`. When you assign to it:

```
Sublist current = list->sublists[sublist_number];
```

You are assigning to a `Sublist` instance another instance, which is obtained by copying the whole content to the destination. Which is what happens.

Then you modify `current` but you are modifying a copy of the original. You could reassign it back, eg:

```
Sublist current = list->sublists[sublist_number];
/* alter current */
list->sublists[sublist_number] = current;
```

But this doesn't make sense as you don't really need a copy but you want to modify the original data.

That's why you use `*`, so that now current is a `Sublist*` variable. It's not an instance of `Sublist` but a pointer to a (hopefully) existing instance of a `Sublist`. Now each modification done through `current` reflects to the original data because there is not another instance.

Comment: Thanks dude! I think I had an instance of "rubber duck debugging" - after I finished typing it up I realized that if current and sublists[sublist_number] were now independent, I wasn't modifying the latter by changing the former - which if I understand you right, is what you pointed out.

Comment: @Chris: Rubber ducks are remarkably good debugging aids.  And yes, I think you've understood what Jack was saying — and it's basically what I said too, but Jack beat me by 30 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

I'm glad you were able to fix the code; that's the correct fix to judge from your stated requirements.  Explaining why is a little harder.

You have a pointer `list` passed to the function.  That means you can modify the structure it points at.  When you used `Sublist current = list->sublists[sublist_number];` you created a copy of the specific sublist from the structure because `current` is a simple local structure.  When you used `Sublist *current = &list->sublists[sublist_number];`, you were left with a pointer to a subsection of the original structure, and you could use the pointer to modify what it points at.

This isn't any different from:

```
int current = list->int_array[i];
```

vs

```
int *current = &list->int_array[i];
```

I've changed the types (and invented a new element in your structure), but the underlying ideas are the same.  The first one is a copy of the value from the structure, the second points at the data in the structure so that the value in the structure can be modified.

Comment: Thanks for the analogy to the simpler situation!